# Have Angular modules reduced the need for barrels?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I am working on a project that has made use of barrels to import and export components, services etc. I understand the concept and use though did come across an article on Reddit where it was suggested barrels were replaced with the introduction of Angular modules. I understand both concepts but potentially not to the detail that would highlight difference use cases for each.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to my question after digging through the Angular documentation and Angular module features.

Barrels are explained in the Angular glossary but it does also go on to say that 'you can often achieve the same result using Angular modules instead'.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B

The ability to 'export' a component, directive and/or pipe also helped me to achieve the same result. I did not have a solid understanding of this concept prior.

> Export declarable classes that components in other modules are able to reference in their templates. These are your public classes. If you don't export a class, it stays private, visible only to other component declared in this module.
>
> You can export any declarable class—components, directives, and pipes—whether it's declared in this module or in an imported module.
>
> You can re-export entire imported modules, which effectively re-exports all of their exported classes. A module can even export a module that it doesn't import.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-what-to-export

In summary, it does look as though the need for barrels was replaced with the introduction of Angular modules. But use of barrels can still be applied.

Comment: Modules and Barrels are different since you can have a barrel for import many modules. I think what you talking of is the feature of a module to export components and other stuff that it imports first, doing those avaiable for every other module that imports the module which exported the component. It is the way used to work with "module over module" For example you import childModule, which export childComponent, in your rootModule and you can use the childComponent in the rootModule. It acts as a barrel here but it isn't.  Sense of barrel is 'package'. Sense of modules is encapsulation.